# How can I get a sensor's name?

Tags: android, sensors

I want to programatically get a [`Sensor`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Sensor.html)'s name. Say the name of the ambient light sensor.

How can I get its name?

Comment: This question is a documentation question. It is meant to document a rather less known feature of the Sensor class.

Comment: Good question but I think it should be more precise as people here misunderstanding it. See the answers.

Comment: How can I be more specific than _Say the name of the ambient light sensor._?

Comment: Actually that seems like you are giving an example. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you have to obtain an instance of the [`SensorManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html), then get the desired service instance from the manager.

```
String sm = Context.SENSOR_SERVICE;
SensorManager sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(sm);

/*
 * We get the light sensor in this example.
 */
Sensor someSensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_LIGHT);

/*
 * Always perform a null check on sensors since your device
 * may not have that sensor.
 */
if (null != someSensor) {
    String sensorName = someSensor.getName();
}
```

You get the name using the Sensor's [`getName()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Sensor.html#getName%28%29) method.

Answer (score 8):

Use the sensor manager to query *(all or [certain types](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Sensor.html) of)* available sensors. Then use `Sensor.getName()` to get the name of an individual sensor.

```
SensorManager sm = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
List<Sensor> list = sm.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_ALL);

for(Sensor s : list) {
    Log.d("SENSORS", s.getName());
}
```

Example output from the snippet above:

```
11-14 12:26:47.549: D/SENSORS(911): BMA150 3-axis Accelerometer
11-14 12:26:47.559: D/SENSORS(911): AK8973 3-axis Magnetic field sensor
11-14 12:26:47.559: D/SENSORS(911): AK8973 Orientation sensor
11-14 12:26:47.559: D/SENSORS(911): CM3602 Proximity sensor
11-14 12:26:47.559: D/SENSORS(911): CM3602 Light sensor
11-14 12:26:47.559: D/SENSORS(911): Gravity Sensor
11-14 12:26:47.559: D/SENSORS(911): Linear Acceleration Sensor
11-14 12:26:47.559: D/SENSORS(911): Rotation Vector Sensor
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort. However I did not ask for a complete list of sensors but for the name of a particular sensor. As stated in my comment on the question this question is meant to be a self-documentation question.

Comment: Ok right, didn't include `getDefaultSensor()` in here. Upvoted your answer. Also I wasn't aware that this is a self-documentation question when I posted. I'd say write a short sentence in the question to emphasize that and edit it out when you're done in the future. This way it's obvious for everyone. I'll keep this since example output is still relevant, also people might end up with google here for both problems.

Answer (score 0):

With the [`getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_ALL)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html#getSensorList%28int%29) you can get all the sensors within the device.

```
SensorManager sensorManager
    = (SensorManager)getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
sensorManager.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_ALL);
```